# synthetic division question.

Tags: polynomials

Synthetic division is possible when the Divisior is in the form of $x+a$ or $x-a$. but what if the divisor is in the form of $x^2+a$, $x^2-a$, $x^3-a$,... and higher powers. how can we perform synthetic division in such cases.

Thanks

Comment: Does this help? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_division#Expanded_synthetic_division

Comment: @@ΘΣΦ GenSan, what if the divisor is $x^2-a$ or $x^2+x+a$?

Comment: ##Jonas Meyer,  what if the form is $x^2-a$? will it be $x=\pm \sqrt {a}$?

Comment: I do not understand the question in the previous comment.  You could divide separately by the linear factors though.  The reference linked takes the polynomial as it is, even if not degree $1$.

Comment: @ Jonas Meyer, you mean once with $\sqrt {a}$ and again with $-\sqrt {a}$?

Comment: @occasionaluser Are you interested in both quotient and remainder, or the remainder only?

Comment: @occasionaluser Yes, you could do that.

Comment: ##dxiv,  with both quotient as well as remainder 
.

Comment: @occasionaluser Then you need to do either the long division, or the expanded synthetic division pointed out already. If you needed the remainder, only, then there are significant shortcuts.

Comment: @##dxiv,  yeah I know that there is remainder theorem for finding the remainder only. but what is meant by expanded synthetic division.  could you please show?

Comment: @occasionaluser Follow the link posted by Jonas Meyer in the first comment.

Comment: @occasionaluser,  you can do it by assuming $x^2=y$.

Answer (score 1):

For the particular case of divisors in the form $x^n-a$ it is possible to replace the long division with $n$ synthetic divisions.

For a polynomial $P(x)$ being divided by $x^3-a$ for example, group the powers of $x$ in $P$ according to the remainder $\bmod 3$ and write it as:

$$
P(x) = P_0(x^3) + x P_1(x^3) + x^2P_2(x^3) 
$$

Use synthetic division to calculate the quotients and remainders of the following:

$$
P_k(x) = (x-a)Q_k(x) + r_k \quad\quad \text{for} \;\; k=0,1,2
$$

Then:

$$
P(x)=(x^3-a)Q(x) + R(x)
$$

where $Q(x) = Q_0(x^3) + xQ_1(x^3)+x^2Q_2(x^3)$ and $R(x)=r_0+r_1x+r_2x^2\,$.

---

[ *EDIT* ] Following is a fully worked out example for $P(X)=x^4-6x^3+16x^2-25x+10$ (the polynomial was borrowed from another, unrelated question) being divided by $x^3-2$.

- Group the powers:

$$P(X)=x^4-6x^3+16x^2-25x+10= (-6x^3+10) + x\cdot (x^3-25) + x^2 \cdot 16$$

$$
\iff
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
 P_0(x) & = -6x+10 \\
 P_1(x) & = x - 25 \\
 P_2(x) &= 16
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

- Divide $P_k$ by $x-2$ and determine $Q_k,r_k$ by synthetic division:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat}{3}
 P_0(x) & = -6x+10 && = -6(x-2) - 2\\
 P_1(x) & = x - 25 && = (x-2) - 23\\
 P_2(x) & = 16 && = 16
\end{alignat}
\end{cases}
$$

$$
\iff
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
 Q_0(x) & = -6 \,,\;\; r_0 = -2\\
 Q_1(x) & = 1  \,,\;\; r_1 = - 23\\
 Q_2(x) & = 0  \,,\;\; r_2 = 16
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

- Calculate $Q,R$:

$$
Q(x) = Q_0(x^3) + xQ_1(x^3)+x^2Q_2(x^3) = -6 +x+ x^2 \cdot 0 = x-6\\
R(x)=r_0+r_1x+r_2x^2=16x^2-23 x-2\,$$

- Verify that indeed:

$$x^4-6x^3+16x^2-25x+10=(x^3-2)(x-6)+ 16x^2-23 x -2$$

Comment: @@##dxiv, could you show me an example?

Comment: @occasionaluser I edited an example in.